# Can anyone help me?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to save all records of one table into another table where email will be match. I use $data variable. Right now $data contains 3 complete arrays, but when I complete save action then only last array is inserted.

Why i am getting this logical error?

````
        $data=Product::where('email','like',$email)->get();
        
            $order=new Order();
            if($data){
            foreach($data as $dt){
                $order->order_name=$dt->product_name;
                $order->order_quantity=$dt->product_quantity;
                $order->order_total=$dt->product_total;
                $order->email=$email;
                $order->name=$req->fullname;
                
                $order->address=$req->address;
                $order->phone=$req->phone;
                $order->save();
                $dt->delete();
            }
            
                return redirect('/')->with('msg','Order Placed Successfully');
            
            }
            else{
                return redirect('/')->with('msg_f','Order not Placed');
            }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Let me get this right, you want to save all records to another table when the emails match?

```
$data=Product::where('email','like',$email)->get();
```

Why are you using like?

```
$data=Product::where('email','=',$email)->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries

Comment: 'like' or '=' is not a issue. as i above mentioned that variable data contains all arrays when i dump. but when i save then this logical error happens.